# Proper Way of Recording Page Views

Tags: php

What is the proper way, using PHP, to record web page views?  I believe that currently we just record a view each time a page is hit on, but I am assuming that is including hits from bots, or other things we don't want to be recording.

How can we just record real legit views into our DB and not include stuff that shouldn't be counted as an actual page view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [google analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics)

To set up the web tracking code:

> Find the tracking code snippet for your property. 
>   Sign in to your Google Analytics account, and select the Admin tab. ...
>       Find your tracking code snippet. ...
>       Copy the snippet. ...
>       Paste your snippet (unaltered, in its entirety) into every web page you want to track. ...
>       Check your setup.

Comment: I already have that set up.  Our site is a marketplace, so we need to show our users how many pageviews their products are receiving, so we need to record this info into the DB apart from GA.

Comment: @CRAIG  Add the events for products from GA

Comment: So I can use the GA api to display pageviews? @Piyush

Comment: @CRAIG  check the link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: And this one for specific product https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Answer (score 0):

1) Ignore any known bots that visits your web page. (best use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/))

2) Use Ajax call at the end of page to get rid of bouncers (visitors that opens web by mistake and closes it before everything is loaded).

3) I assume you can call Ajax in some delay, so robots will already has left your page and visitor is still browsing it.

4) Record IP addresses and (if possible) some device identifier to find unique visitors.

Comment: What about bots that are indexing the page for ranking purposes, etc., i.e. Google?

Comment: @CRAIG Than allow them. Use robots.txt file to prevent robots. http://www.robotstxt.org/